# Call to the “Get_Item_Quantity” function in the web service (trying to call soap api using magento restful services)

Tags: xml, rest-api, magento2.3.3, web-services, soap-api

I have a function in an XML document and I want to return its parameters. My knowledge of connecting the two services is very limited. Do I need to create some middleware or is it possible just to call from Magento Swagger? Any help or resources to point me in the right direction would be super!

Function name: `Get_Item_Quantity`
This function takes `Type`, `Code fields` and returns `Qty1`, `Qty2`, `Qty3`, and `Qty4`
**Parameters:**

```
Type = 0 – input value
Code = ‘product100317’ – input value
Qty 1 – return value
Qty 2 – return value
Qty 3 – return value
Qty 4 – return value
```

How do I go about this?
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI"
             targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty1" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty2" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty3" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty4" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="EntryNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderFound" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderNo" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="SalesOrderLineNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderETADate" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderItemNo" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI">
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="date"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="custNo" type="string"/>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="extDocNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="boolean"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q1="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q1:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q2="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q2:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q3="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q3:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q4="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q4:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyWSAPI_Port">
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MyWSAPI_Binding" type="tns:MyWSAPI_Port">
        <binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI:Get_Item_ETA_Date" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"
                       style="document"/>
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Get_Item_Quantity" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:GetSalesOrderETA" style="document"/>
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="myWSAPI">
        <port name="myWSAPI_Port" binding="tns:MyWSAPI_Binding">
            <address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                     location="http://test.myapi.local:7947/my/path/here/myWSAPI"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You're trying to call this SOAP API from a rest endpoint you're making through Magento? Or..?

Comment: yes, that is correct. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you already created a custom Rest API and the only missing piece of the puzzle is API call. Although I have added all steps to create a custom API as well.

This is how I am calling SOAP API using soap call.

1. Create CustomInterface.php in path app/code/Test/CustomApi/Api/CustomInterface.php

   ```
   namespace Test\CustomApi\Api;

   interface CustomInterface
   {
       /**
        * GET for Qty api
        * @param int $type
        * @param string $code
        * @return string
        */

        public function getQty($type,$code);
   }
   ```
2. Create Custom.php in path app/code/Test/CustomApi/Model/Api/Custom.php

   ```
   namespace Test\CustomApi\Model\Api;

   use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

   class Custom
   {
       protected $logger;

       public function __construct(
           LoggerInterface $logger
       )
       {
           $this->logger = $logger;
       }

       /**
        * @inheritdoc
        */
       public function getQty($type,$code) {
           $response = ['success' => false];

           try {
               // Logic to call soap service here
               $qty = $this->getItemQty($type,$code);
               $response = ['success' => true, 'qty' => $qty];

           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
               $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
           }

           $returnArray = json_encode($response);
           return $returnArray;
       }


       /**
        * Soap API call 
        *
        * @param int $type
        * @param string $code
        * @return void
        */
       public function getItemQty($type,$code)
       {
           $soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
             <soap12:Body>
               <Get_Item_Quantity xmlns="http://test.com/">
                   <Type>' . $type . '</Type>
                   <Code>' . $code . '</Code>
               </Get_Item_Quantity>
             </soap12:Body>
           </soap12:Envelope>';
           $header = array(
               "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
               "Accept: text/xml",
           );
           $soapHandler = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/");
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapRequest);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
           curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
           //header('Content-type: text/xml');
           $result = curl_exec($soapHandler);
           $qtyData = array();
           if ($result === false) {
               $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soapHandler);
               curl_close($soapHandler);
               $this->logger->info($err);
           } else {
               curl_close($soapHandler);
               $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
               $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
               $result = $xml->xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body');
               $res = $result[0]->Get_Item_Quantity_Result;
               $qtyData = simplexml_load_string($res);
           }
           return $qtyData;
       }
   }
   ```

You should be able see this endpoint in swagger. http://URL/swagger

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help on this and i'm testing it right now. I'm assuming that i plug my Soap URL into where you put http://test.com/ correct? @kamlesh.bar

Comment: Are you there? Put the link to my destination where my xmlSoap file resides where you put test.com? @kamlesh.bar

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question, you need  to change URL 1.<Get_Item_Quantity xmlns="http://test.com/" > 2.  curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/"); here.

Comment: Yes, do i change it to where my endpoint soap xml document resides like here : http://test.myapi.local:7947/my/path/here/myWSAPI?????

Comment: How did you get to that swagger page in particular where you type in the testCustomApiCustomV1? Currently i'm on my swagger page but i don't know how to enter the information.

Comment: My website is here: http://164.90.154.246/swagger @kamlesh.bar

Comment: This interface is not showing up with the other endpoints on my build.

Comment: Hi Mate, Looks you haven't added endpoint.  please checkout this basic steps to create custom API. 
https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/

Comment: Oh thank you .. i was missing the module.xml file and the registration.php file as well as the webapi.xml and di.xml files. Thank you so much for reference.

Comment: When i try to upgrade i get this error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ' \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/community/app/code/Test/CustomApi/registration.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/community/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}('/usr/share/ngin...')
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/community/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(31): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)

Comment: #3 /app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(34): Magento\No#4 nginx/html/community/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(73): require('/usr/share/ngin...')
#5 nginx/html/community/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(63): composerRequiref7812b4783c6a0400f3680294725bf64('b4cf39431a4b949...', '/usr/share/ngin...')
#6 /nginx/html/community/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitf7812b4783c6a0400f3680294725bf64::getLoader( in /usr/share/nginx/html/community/app/code/Test/CustomApi/registration.php on line 3nComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}()

Comment: I think I got it all together but need a bit of help running this to pull my data... Can you help me with the steps to execute this correctly. Here it is loaded on swagger: http://164.90.154.246/swagger#/testCustomApiCustomV1/testCustomApiCustomV1GetQtyPost

Comment: error logs: [2021-03-25 18:28:50] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-605cd66205bf7; Message: Class Test\CustomApi\Model\Api\CustomInterface does not exist {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: -1): Report ID: webapi-605cd66205bf7; Message: Class Test\\CustomApi\\Model\\Api\\CustomInterface does not exist at /usr/share/nginx/html/community/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Test\\CustomApi\\Model\\Api\\CustomInterface does not exist at /usr/share/nginx/html/community/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24)"} []

Comment: I've confirmed the file is there but i keep getting this error in my logs.

Comment: check di.xml file. It should have <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\CustomApi\Api\CustomInterface" type="Test\CustomApi\Model\Api\Custom"/>
</config>